# Excel: how to insert data in the different sheets by taking them from different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need your help. I have a reference sheet that contains data organized in 8 columns. I have to create 8 sheets, each of them must contain only one column. The first sheet in column A contains the data of the first column of the reference sheet, the second sheet, also in column A, contains the data of the second column of the reference sheet and so on ... How can I dynamically create the references to be inserted in the formulas ? instead of changing them manually?

Comment: You should provide the source table and the result you want for each Worksheets.

Answer (score 1):

Place the reference sheet after the 8 new ones you made and use the formula:

```
=INDEX('reference'!A:H,,SHEET())
```

in cell A1 of each sheet and it will do what you want. If you use this you will get a 0 in every blank cell, so you can add in an IF function to the above:

```
=IF(INDEX('reference'!A:H,,SHEET())=0,"",INDEX('reference'!A:H,,SHEET()))
```

If this doesn't work you can use this formula in cell A1 and drag it down as far as you need.

```
=INDEX('reference'!A:H,ROW(),SHEET())
```

or

```
=IF(INDEX('reference'!A:H,ROW(),SHEET())=0,"",INDEX('reference'!A:H,ROW(),SHEET()))
```

This formula uses sheet reference so if you change the order of the sheets the data will change also, so you should copy and paste values to avoid this issue. being that you have to de that, it's probably easier to just copy them manually by selecting the entire column.